# grep two integers and compare them

Tags: bash, grep, compare

I am trying to write a script that does the following:

1. Given a string that look like this "There are 5 apples and 3 oranges"
2. Extract the two integers (5, 3)
3. Compare them

I got the extract part done.

```
NUM=echo $String | grep -o "[0-9]\+"
```

But NUM will be something like this:

```
5
3
\n
```

I tried `${NUM[0]}` and `${NUM[@]}` just to get the first value but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The way you assign to `NUM` is incorrect.
So is the `grep` pattern in your post.
Write like this:

```
input='There are 5 apples and 3 oranges'
nums=($(grep -Eo '[0-9]+' <<< "$input"))
```

`${nums[0]}` will contain the first number, `${nums[1]}` the 2nd, and so on.

If the input comes from a command:

```
nums=($(cmd | grep -Eo '[0-9]+'))
```

Comment: @AlbertYip I updated my answer with examples for those cases.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with process substitution and `mapfile`:

```
$ mapfile -t nums < <(grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]+' <<< 'There are 5 apples and 3 oranges')
$ declare -p nums
declare -a nums='([0]="5" [1]="3")'
```

This makes sure that only newlines separate array elements. This wouldn't be a problem in this case as the search terms are sequences of numbers, but it's a robust approach that would work for any pattern.

Notice that `mapfile` requires Bash 4.0 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

with `GNU awk`:

```
gawk '{if($1>$2){print $1">"$2}else if($1<$2){print $1"<"$2} else {print $1"="$2}}' FPAT='[0-9]+' <<<'There are 5 apples and 8 oranges'
```

> The value of FPAT should be a string that provides a regular
>   expression. This regular expression describes the contents of each
>   field.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for FPAT:

```
$ echo 'There are 5 apples and 3 oranges' |
    awk -v FPAT='[0-9]+' '{print ($1 > $2 ? "greater" : "lesser")}'
greater
$ echo 'There are 2 apples and 3 oranges' |
    awk -v FPAT='[0-9]+' '{print ($1 > $2 ? "greater" : "lesser")}'
lesser
```